# What're the differences in float type in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, webgl

I'm porting a shader from OpenGL to WebGL, and I'm a bit confused when I see smth like
`float  refCorrection    = clamp(NdotL + fVelvet * 2 + .5f, 0.5f, 1.f);`
Exactly, is there any diffenrence between `.5f`, `0.5f` and `0.5`?

Comment: As far as GLSL is concerned, 0.5 is legal and 0.5f is illegal. C and C++ have such a notion to distinguish between single and double precision constants, GLSL does not. I wouldn't know if the dialect used in WebGL is more "permissive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is C++ calling code, `0.5` (no suffix) means `double` and `0.5f` and `.5f` are `float`, both indicating the same number, the leading zeroes do not mean anything.

In GLSL all these are floats and the leading zero do not matter either. If you want a double you need the suffix `lf`. Note however that doubles were only added since OpenGL and GLSL version 4. The f suffix was not always present and is not really necessary anyway as float is the default.

Comment: Is double supported in hardware anywhere?  I didn't think it was yet, but I could be mistaken.  I mean it might parse, but it ends up as float regardless.

Comment: @Robinson: Could very well be, I never needed it so didn't really check the HW support. I just knew it was added to the spec.